# Dependency Injection with property wrapper swift

Tags: swift

I followed a blog for Dependency injection container and it has always worked except now I need to add an edge case which is not handled by the tutorial.

To handle this DI swift property wrapper was used like this

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Injected<T> {
    
    private let keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedValues, T>
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get { InjectedValues[keyPath] }
        set { InjectedValues[keyPath] = newValue }
    }
    
    init(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedValues, T>) {
        self.keyPath = keyPath
    }
}

struct InjectedValues {
    
    /// This is only used as an accessor to the computed properties within extensions of `InjectedValues`.
    private static var current = InjectedValues()
    
    /// A static subscript for updating the `currentValue` of `InjectionKey` instances.
    static subscript<K>(key: K.Type) -> K.Value where K : InjectionKey {
        get { key.currentValue }
        set { key.currentValue = newValue }
    }
    
    /// A static subscript accessor for updating and references dependencies directly.
    static subscript<T>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<InjectedValues, T>) -> T {
        get { current[keyPath: keyPath] }
        set { current[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue }
    }
}

public protocol InjectionKey {

    /// The associated type representing the type of the dependency injection key's value.
    associatedtype Value

    /// The default value for the dependency injection key.
    static var currentValue: Self.Value { get set }
}
```

Then to implement this, I would give an example of my current implementation which works

```
protocol VerifyPhoneViewModelRouter: ViewControllerRoutes {
    var onBackTapped: (() -> Void)? { get set }
}

struct VerifyPhoneViewModelRouterKey: InjectionKey {
    static var currentValue: VerifyPhoneViewModelRouter = VerifyPhoneViewModel()
}

extension InjectedValues {
    var verifyPhoneViewModelRouter: VerifyPhoneViewModelRouter {
        get { Self[VerifyPhoneViewModelRouterKey.self] }
        set { Self[VerifyPhoneViewModelRouterKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

class VerifyPhoneViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable, VerifyPhoneViewModelRouter {
    var onBackTapped: (() -> Void)?
    var contdWithPhoneModel: ContdWithPhoneModel.Request
    init(contdWithPhoneModel: ContdWithPhoneModel.Request) {
        self.contdWithPhoneModel = contdWithPhoneModel
        super.init()
    }
}
```

This how ever gives error because I have to pass the struct model `ContdWithPhoneModel.Request` as parameter into the class at `VerifyPhoneViewModelRouterKey` currentValue.

My question now is how can I handle this edge case?

Here is a link to the original article https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/

No comment area so I don't know how to progress from here and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific. What error are you getting? You said that your example works, and then you said that it gives an error; which is it? What exactly do you see as an *edge case*?

Comment: `VerifyPhoneViewModel` requires `ContdWithPhoneModel.Request`

Comment: I can't assign currentValue because the model struct is required. I want to be able to pass the model class.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same blog to create some sort of dependency injection framework, and I also needed to inject repositories into the viewModel.

I found a workaround modifiying a bit the InjectionKeys, to have a *computedValue* and a *currentValue*, like so:

```
public protocol InjectionKey {
    // the associated type representing the type of the dependency injection key's value 
    associatedtype Value

    // The default value for the dependency injection key (computed, as, it can have injected properties).
    static var computedValue: Value { get }
            
    // Default value returned by the injection key. Usually, is the computed value, but can be overwriten.
    static var currentValue: Value { get set }
}
```

And from there, I can inject repositories dependencies in the computedValue, and then assign the computedValue into the currentValue, for example, like this:

```
private struct PackagesViewModelKey: InjectionKey {
    static var computedValue: PackagesViewModel {
        @Injected(\.packagesRepositoryProvider) var packagesRepository: PackagesService
        @Injected(\.metaInfoRepositoryProvider) var metaRepository: MetaInfoService
        
        return PackagesViewModel(
            packagesRepository: packagesRepository,
            metaRepository: metaRepository
        )
    }
    static var currentValue = computedValue
}
```

As you can see, the computedValue uses the same injection, and instantiates the viewModel with the dependencies right into the initializer.

The currentValue holds the singleton of the viewModel, and it's what's returned when using the property wrapper to inject the instance, so, it's the same instance injected everywhere. This has some pros and some cons, so be careful.

Also, since the currentValue holding the instance to be injected, it's a "static var", it's a singleton which will live throughout the app's lifetime, so, again, be careful on how you use it, since stored values in the viewModel won't "reset", since, well, the viewModel (or any other instance injected), won't be discarded by the ARC.

I'm currently trying to improve upon this, but so far, it works great.